# Integrating mqtt with apache nifi

Tags: mqtt, apache-nifi, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto client with the sudo command

`sudo apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto-clients`

The above command by default installs mosquitto version 1.4.8.

But in documentation to integrate mosquitto with Apache nifi it tells to install `libmosquitto1`.

what is libmosquitto1 ?

Do I need to install it although I have installed the mosquitto client ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libmosquitto1 is a library that 3rd party Mosquitto clients use to talk to Mosquitto. You've installed the mosquitto server and the clients that ship as part of Mosquitto, but if you haven't installed libmosquitto1 then you haven't installed the libraries that other software will need.

Just install it with

`sudo apt-get install libmosquitto1`

and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Romkey for clarifying my doubt and to make me understand the difference among all these. I appreciate your time and answer. Have a great day ahead :)